# How do I uninstall an app from my Mac?

Tags: macbook-pro, applications, macos

I know I'm a bit silly here, and I've just recently switched from Windows to Mac. All I would do on a PC is press Win+X and then the F key to get to "Programs and Features" window, and search for the app from the list and then uninstall them. So I was wondering if there is anything similar on Mac as well.

Comment: https://www.howtogeek.com/231496/how-to-uninstall-applications-on-a-mac-everything-you-need-to-know/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For most apps, it's easy as navigating to your Applications folder in the Finder, then dragging the application to the Trash icon in your Dock. You can also right-click and select 'Move to Trash', or hit ⌘-delete.

I should also add, many apps store your settings and data in a different directory which doesn't get deleted simply by deleting the app in the Applications folder. This is both good and bad. If you ever reinstall the app, all your settings and data will still be in place. Keeping these extra files around doesn't really do macOS any harm. Although if you're concerned about removing EVERYTHING for a particular app, it can be tough to make sure you get everything. There are various utilities that make this a bit easier, one I've used in the past is [AppZapper](https://appzapper.com).

If you're curious, these files are usually in `~/Library/Application Support` and `~/Library/Preferences`.

Comment: With some exceptions, the items that are left behind are completely ignored by the system and don't impact performance or anything else. If an app was purchased through the App Store, it's definitely sufficient to put it in the Trash. If not, I suggest Googling or checking the developer's website for uninstall instructions. There may be an uninstaller app, or you may be guided to move additional files to the trash.

Answer (score -5):

```
sudo rm -rf /Applications/youapp.app
```

Comment: Putting `sudo rm -rf` in the hands of a new user is like handing a small child a loaded gun.

Comment: I agree 100% with @Tetsujin Also, if the OP has only just recently switched to a Mac, there's a better than average chance of them using either El Capitan or Sierra, in which case the Terminal command wouldn't work without first disabling SIP.