# Can a macOS App define which folders + files + settings (Background Tasks, Notifications) are removed upon uninstalling the app?

Tags: macos, applications, notifications, login-items

I'm using a macOS App - and I'm wondering how to define which folders created by the app are removed when using Cleaner-apps such as `CleanMyMacX` or other such uninstaller tools.

So far it seems that there should be a removal of `~/Library/Application Support/AppName` at least, and also Background Tasks removal, and Notifications removal.

Upon installing the app, it asks for permission to send Notifications, and also adds a Background / Login Item task.

My expectation is that if I use a tool to remove the app, those folders / System Settings configurations should definitely be removed. This does not seem to be so.

So how does an app communicate which folders "are available for deletion" to these removal apps?

The ideal situation is that I'm able to send this information, in the form of "make these changes" to the app developers, and they can make the correct switches / changes so that the app is cleanly removed by deleting, or uninstalling. But unless if I know what type of information to send, I cannot help them help me/us (endusers).

But I have no idea where to look or how to find this type of information.

Are there best practices that are listed, say, by Apple, somewhere, or something that can aid in this?

Comment: Is there a particular app giving you trouble?

Comment: For CleanMyMac X, I have the feeling the opaque binary file `CleanMyMac X.app/Contents/Resources/info.cmmkb` ("CleanMyMac X Knowledge Base", maybe?) has to do with this...

Answer (score 1):

There is no best practice when it comes to uninstalling apps.

There is no central location on macOS where apps store information regarding files and folders they have created. Apps do not communicate which folders "are available for deletion".

There are some cleaner apps which can be configured to watch what each app opens and store that away for future cleaning. I don't recommend doing that.

The free (and paid) cleaner apps make a pretty good job of looking in all the places which might need to be cleaned. The most commonly used is the free [AppCleaner](https://freemacsoft.net/appcleaner/).

To be honest I am bit wary of MacPaw's CleanMyMacX as it offers so much in one place without being really good at anything (my personal view - others may disagree). Better to use AppCleaner.

Some large complex apps (e.g. Adobe's) provide their own uninstaller app or provide details on their web site about how to cleanly uninstall.

If you are having trouble with a particular app and AppCleaner doesn't remove it completely, go to the developers web site and see if it has uninstallation instructions.

Apart from some additions, this is pretty much the same answer as [How do I uninstall an app from my Mac?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/273580/how-do-i-uninstall-an-app-from-my-mac)

Answer (score 0):

**So how does an app communicate which folders "are available for deletion" to these removal apps?**

I'm not sure that they do. Cleaner apps just look for folders and files that have the app's name or bundle ID, and delete them.

You are correct that they can miss files; or worse, delete files that belong to another process.

Sandboxed apps will put everything in `~/Library/Containers`, and deleting their named folder inside there will delete everything they have added. This is the 'modern' way, used in iOS.

But, by and large, most apps usually leave only a very small number of files, which will do nothing if the app itself is deleted.

Complex apps that install lots of components tend to provide uninstallers, or instructions for what to delete.

I myself am wary of using any 'cleaning' app; or any 'routine maintenance' tool.